# Postgresql 9.6: Query specific ranges of a JSONB array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I use Postgresql 9.6 currently and been trying since hours to get the following solved in the most efficient way:

My example table:

```
id | data
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10 | {"scores": [{"u": "Peter", s: 120}, {"u": "Joe", s: 100}, {"u": "Pam", s: 70}, {"u": "Lisa", s: 120}]}
11 | {"scores": [{"u": "Mae", s: 320}, {"u": "Max", s: 230}, {"u": "Moe", s: 170}, {"u": "Mini", s: 120}]}
12 | {"scores": [{"u": "Jack", s: 140}, {"u": "John", s: 110}, {"u": "Wes", s: 70}, {"u": "Mick", s: 20}]}
```

I need a query to get the top 2 Usernames (`u`) of each row.

So my result should look like this:

```
users
-----
Peter
Joe
Mae
Max
Jack
John
```

And a query to get the 2nd and 3rd usernames:

```
users
-----
Joe
Pam
Max
Moe
John
Wes
```

What would be the most efficient way to solve this? My real tables have arrays with 100-400 elements and about 1500 rows.

Comment: If you need to do this often, then maybe think about the advice given in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) regarding normal arrays: "*Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements*". This is also true for arrays hidden inside JSON object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First 2 usernames:

```
SELECT scores -> 'u'
FROM (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) rn, scores
  FROM (
    SELECT id, data, jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'scores') AS scores
    FROM scores
  ) s1
) s2
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

2nd and 3rd usernames:

```
SELECT scores -> 'u'
FROM (
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id) rn, scores
  FROM (
    SELECT id, data, jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'scores') AS scores
    FROM scores
  ) s1
) s2
WHERE rn = 2 OR rn = 3;
```

Another option would be:

```
SELECT username
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(ARRAY [(data #> '{scores,0,u}') :: TEXT, (data #> '{scores,1,u}') :: TEXT]) username
  FROM scores
) usernames WHERE username NOTNULL;
```

2nd and 3rd usernames:

```
SELECT username
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(ARRAY [(data #> '{scores,1,u}') :: TEXT, (data #> '{scores,2,u}') :: TEXT]) username
  FROM scores
) usernames WHERE username NOTNULL;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomer this was exactly what i was missing.